# Don't deserialize nested JSON string

Tags: c#, json

If i have a JSON property which holds a **string** of another JSON block, not actual JSON but a string containing JSON, how do i stop Deserialize from attempting to deserialize that string?

**FIG A**: my example structure with JSON string:

```
{
    "name" : "parent",
    "data" : "{
        "name" : "child",
        "data" : "foobar",
        }",
}
```

**FIG B**: an example of normal nested JSON

```
{
    "name" : "parent",
    "data" : 
    {
        "name" : "child",
        "data" : "foobar",
    },
}
```

So from this when i deserialize the parent object in **FIG A**, i should get a single object with 2 string properties, one called 'name' containing 'parent' and one called 'data' containing '{ "name" : "child", "data" : "foobar" }'

But when i try to do this, i get an **error**.

Here's the exact **JSON** its trying to parse:

```
"{ \"result\" : true, \"status\" : \"success\", \"data\" : \"{ \"id\" : 1, \"name\" : \"demo\", \"pixeldata\" : [{ \"time\" : \"1\", \"colour\" : \"#ff5357\"},{ \"time\" : \"2\", \"colour\" : \"#2424ff\"},{ \"time\" : \"3\", \"colour\" : \"#ff0d13\"},{ \"time\" : \"4\", \"colour\" : \"#f7ff4a\"},{ \"time\" : \"5\", \"colour\" : \"#fa24ff\"},{ \"time\" : \"6\", \"colour\" : \"#ff3e43\"}] }\" }"
```

Here's the exact **error** message:

```
"After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: i. Path 'data', line 1, position 54."
```

And here's the **structs** it should be parsing into:

```
public struct ServerResponse
{
    public bool result;
    public string status;
    public string data;
}

public struct Display
{
    public int id;
    public string name;
    public Data[] pixeldata;
}

public struct Data
{
    public float time;
    public string colour;
}
```

Here's the exact line of **code** that's causing the exception:

```
response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<API.ServerResponse>(_raw_response_data);
```

**Any clues?**

Comment: Yep, the unexpected character is a double quote. It is not the fact it is JSON inside the string. It is that the double quotes in the inner JSON are not escaped, so it creates invalid syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause is in the serialization of the string you provided as an example, (the one you say it's the exact JSON it's trying to parse)

`\"data\" : \"{ \"id\" : 1,`  is:  `"data" : "{ "id" : 1`

The inner double-quotes inside the data string aren't escaped.

It should be

`\"data\" : \"{ \\\"id\\\" : 1,`, which is `"data" : "{ \"id\" : 1`

Comment: Thanks, i encoded it before adding to the parent and it works perfectly!